# Correct interpretation of the Borde Guth Vilenkin (BGV) theorem?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, time, singularities

I recently watched [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqKObSeim2w) debate between Sean Carroll and William Laine Craig on the topic of theism. At 8:29, Dr. Craig presents his interpretation of the [BGV Theorem](http://creationwiki.org/Borde-Guth-Vilenkin_singularity_theorem), and claims it implies the universe must have had a beginning, and time cannot extend infinitely into the past. At 26:28, Dr. Carroll explains why Craig's argument misrepresents the BGV theorem.

Now I would take a physicists (Dr. Carroll) word any day in this argument. But supposedly, after the debate Dr. Craig emailed Vilenkin about this issue, and Vilenkin allegedly claimed that Craig did not misinterpret the theorem.

I would put a summary of Carroll's and Craig's arguments, but I am afraid I would butcher them so I just mentioned the timestamps and left the link to the video.

Answer (score 2):

Having watched only the referenced sections of the video (the arguments concerning the BGV theorem, and short periods surrounding those marks), I want to note that to the best of my knowledge both Craig and Carroll make themselves guilty of misrepresenting some information to the public, for example Craig's quote of Hawking (dealt with by Carroll) and Carroll bringing up the infinite-time result of the Schrödinger equation (because it might be taken as indicative that it is a relevant result, which I find highly questionable seeing as it can be taken as indication of the Schrödinger equation's incompatability with certain observed events *within* the universe).

Concerning the BGV theorem Craig is correct in saying that the result holds for any geodesic observer with a non-comoving congruence of time-like geodesic test particles which is on average (over the past) expanding (in a generalized sense, within general relativity), in the sense that such an observer geodesic is necessarily past-incomplete. That is not what he says, of course, but to my ears his statement of this is as good as one can expect. That does not imply a creation event. What it does mean is that if e.g. a light-ray passes through a fiducial "cloud" of objects (without interacting), such as can e.g. be taken to be the case *locally* in any cosmological model I have seen, and observes an overall expansion, then that geodesic does end somewhere in the past. I am fairly certain that this is not an in any way controversial result.

Carroll is correct in that the BGV theorem thus does not include *all* models, but it includes a wider range than Carroll's "some" may make it sound like (depending on interpretation, of course).

Ultimately, both the BGV theorem and the quoted paper on the generalized second law may be interpreted as supporting the idea of some sort of "creation event," in the sense that they do not conradict it and serves to narrow down other possibilities. However, in the same way they could then be interpreted as supporting *any* theory they do not contradict. This is often the natural, but certainly not scientific, response of someone who has themselves formed a theory already. They most definitely cannot be taken as proof either way.

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Craig rejects Professor Vilenkin's naturalistic model of the Universe's origins:

http://www.reasonablefaith.org/the-ultimate-question-of-origins-god-and-the-beginning-of-the-universe

Ask yourself how Dr. Craig, who is not a physicist, can appeal to Vilenkin being correct on some things but not others?

Also watch Dr. Craig reject the number zero in his debate with the philosopher Peter Millican:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEw8VzzXcjE

Beginning around the 1:18:00 mark, Craig also rejects all of transfinite arithmetic, never telling his audience, of course, that one of the authors of the BGV theorem, Arvind Borde, is a distinguished professor of mathematics.

Comment: Because Craig disagrees with Vilenkin on some things and not on others... That's a pretty standard thing. It's virtually impossible to agree with someone else on everything. Not alarming in the slightest.

Comment: That's like me, a layperson, disagreeing with Professor Vilenkin on some things; so what?  But, unlike Dr. Craig, I do not deny the number zero.  Most individuals, of course, come to such an understanding sometime between preschool and first grade.

Comment: All of this is still irrelevant to the question. Additionally, appeal to authority is a logical fallacy. I'm asking the same question you are about WLC's disagreement with certain things: so what?

Comment: Dr. Craig does not understand high school physics, let alone General Relativity or QFT.

Comment: From Dr. Vilenkin to WLC, "I think you represented what I wrote about the BGV theorem in my papers and to you personally very accurately." Apparently then, I guess a middle schooler can correctly understand what the BGV theorem implies about our universe.

Comment: I am sure that they can, namely, that the BGV Thereom, like the Equipartition Theorem, is based upon classical physics, which assumes a 4-dimension Lorentzian metric (which Dr. Craig rejects) on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold where superluminal information exchange ("faster than light" communication) is a physical impossibility, hence, the past incompleteness of certain geodesics in inflationary models of the Universe.  Some quatum theories of gravity render the BGV moot; by the way, the authors of the BGV theorem, in their paper, call for "new physics" and not faith in a god; read the paper.

Comment: Again, not really related to the question. I have read the paper. The finitude of the universe is the physics. The origin of the universe is metaphysics.

Comment: Not every cosmologist is of the opinion that the Cosmos must be finite, either in time or space.  The adverb that Professor Vilenkin uses is "probably", which is hardly the 6-sigma confidence interval which modern physicists strive for.  And, Professor Vilenkin is not the only eminent cosmologist in the World today; as Professor Carroll pointed out in his debate with Dr. Craig, Professor Alan Guth, the father of modern inflationary cosmology and one of the authors of the BGV paper, is completely comfortable with the idea of a beginning-less Cosmos.

Comment: 1. 6-sigma would still fall under the category of "probably." He gave no further clarity on how probable is "probably." 
2. 6-sigma is what is used in high-energy physics for new discoveries (new particles, G waves, etc.), and certainly not in cosmological models of the beginning of the universe. 
3. It is not of any concern that not "every cosmologist" thinks something. We should "probably" go with what is "probably" true rather than what is probably not true.

Comment: Besides what Sean Carrol showed, does Guth have anything published that talks about his belief of a beginning-less universe? Because Guth's eternal inflation paper from 2007 says "Although inflation is generically eternal into the future, it is not eternal into the past," and "the inflating region must be incomplete in past directions." And I just saw a video where he said "It certainly looks like the universe as we observe around us, the universe as we know it, definitely had a beginning." Though he mentions there could've been other beginnings prior the beginning of our universe.

Comment: Yeah, Dr. Craig loves to equivocate on words such as "beginning", "Universe", etc.  No one knows; every physicist agrees on that!  Which means that none of this stuff leads to god, much less Calvary.  Yes, our Universe may have had a beginning, but there may be "new physics" discovered someday that leads to a viable model of an eternal, beginning-less multiverse.  Who knows?

Comment: Sure. Current physics suggests a beginning.

Comment: Read Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday, Resnick and Walker, which was voted by the APS as being the leading undergraduate textbook in physics for the 20th century.  Those 3 physicists state that there was nothing prior to the Big Bang.  On the other hand, C. Wetterich published a physical model (Phys. Rev. D 90, 043520 – Published 18 August 2014) of a beginning-less Cosmos; one can be an atheist (which is what I am) either with the position of H.R.W, or Wetterich, or, one of his peers.  As for Professor Vilenkin, he is an agnostic with respect to the existence of God.  Craig is the outlier.

Comment: I will explore Wetterich's paper. The metaphysical beliefs of H.R.W., etc are outside the scope of the question. This theorem (among others) still suggests a beginning, independent of alternative proposed models. Of course there are published proposals of eternal universes; many just redefine 'beginning' in different terms. Aguirre's is a low-entropy hypersurface at the origin of bidirectional arrows of time, HH is an imaginary time boundary that shows a singularity when put back in real time, etc. Of course there was nothing "prior to" the BB as there's no such as thing as "prior to" the BB.

Comment: H.R.W. are representative of the mainstream views of physicists.

Comment: Still irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I do not know how I missed this, but, I did (as, apparently, have a lot of folks!): https://inference-review.com/article/the-beginning-of-the-universe